# Click event on SVG sprite only works with one type of element accessor in JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg, addeventlistener, svg-sprite

I am using the handlebars templating engine

```html
<div class="input-wrapper col-md-12">
    <input id="{{#if type}}{{type}}{{else}}text{{/if}}" name="{{#if type}}{{type}}{{else}}text{{/if}}"
        class="input--default" type="{{#if type}}{{type}}{{else}}text{{/if}}" data-filled="false" {{{data-rules}}}
        {{{data-messages}}} data-input-type="{{#if type}}{{type}}{{else}}text{{/if}}"/>
    <label for="{{#if type}}{{type}}{{else}}text{{/if}}" class="o-input__label">
        {{#if label}}
        {{label}}
        {{else}}
        Label
        {{/if}}
    </label>
    <span class="input-icon__svg-wrapper" id="error-icon">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 18 18" class="input-icon__svg">
            <use xlink:href="{path-to-svg-file}#error"></use>
        </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="input-icon__svg-wrapper" id="password-icon">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 18 18" class="input-icon__svg" pointer-events="none">
            <use xlink:href="{path-to-svg-file}#password" pointer-events="none"></use>
        </svg>
    </span>
</div>
```

```js
// This work
// PS: [5] is the password-icon span
document.querySelectorAll('.input-icon__svg-wrapper')[5].addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e)
})

// This doesn't work
document.querySelector('#password-icon').addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

Can anybody explain to me what is the difference here and why does one work and the other doesn't.

Also, please tell me if there's a better way to handle scripting. Preferably inter-document scripting and not using the `onclick` attribute on the `svg/use` tag

Comment: Is there by any chance that there are multiple elements with the same ID `password-icon`? There is no reason why your first selector will work but the second would not, unless you have duplicate IDs.

Comment: Nope, don't have any such issues

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using handlebars, I looped over this template 4 times.

I was targeting the wrong element, which is why direct indexing worked and not the other method. Apparently I got a `NodeList` array when I ran:

```js
document.querySelector('#password-icon').addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

This made me realise that I had not been properly targeting the element accessor.

Comment: Precisely. If you're looping this template over 4 times then you have duplicated the same ID 4 times. This has nothing to do with NodeList.